# How to show the specific columns which separated by one to more spaces using BASH commands?

Tags: bash, cut

I have different data which were created at different date and time shown below.

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user 157559823 May 23  09:39 1x100.lammpstrj
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user 157560063 Jul  2  08:22 2x200.lammpstrj
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user 157561559 Jul  7  13:13 3x250.lammpstrj
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user 157560934 Jul  9  10:10 4x300.lammpstrj
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user 157566774 Jul 19  11:29 5x350.lammpstrj
```

I hope to show the last column which are file names with suffix .lammpstrj. If I use

```
`ls -latr *.lammpstrj | cut -d ' ' -f 9`
```

I cannot get all file names. I noticed that the multiple spaces between month and day led to such problems. Any universal solution for cases similar to this one? I sincerely appreciate your time and help.

Comment: [Why *not* parse `ls`?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls)

Comment: Don't forget that filenames can have spaces in them, so be careful.

Comment: @Cyrus, Thanks. Yes, you are right. But if such case happened in my data file, any universal solution? I have many data files which have different columns separated by various spaces. Any suggestion? Thanks.

Comment: Why do you use option `-l` (long listing format)?

Comment: try to get the total information. This information would be used by my programs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to view them: `ls -1 *.lammpstrj`

If you want to iterate over them: `for file in *.lammpstrj; do ...`

If you want to store them for later use:

```
files=(*.lammpstrj)
# now do stuff with them, for example print them:
printf "%s\n" "${files[@]}"
# or something else
for file in "${files[@]}"; do ...
```

To get metadata about your files, use `stat`:

```
stat -c "%Y %s %n" *.lammpstrj | while read -r mtime size filename; do
    printf "%s has size %d and was last modified %s\n" \
      "$filename" \
      "$size" \
      "$(date -d "@$mtime" "+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")"
done
```

Or use `-printf` in `find`

Answer (score 1):

If you're just after the filenames, using `find` will get you there:

```
find *.lammpstrj -maxdepth 1 -type f
```

Comment: +1. It can also be useful to add `-maxdepth 1` if you want to restrict `find` to the current directory only.

Comment: This way with find (GNU findutils) 4.7.0-git, I get warning find: warning: you have specified the -maxdepth option after a non-option argument -type, but options are not positional (-maxdepth affects tests specified before it as well as those specified after it).  Please specify options before other arguments.